# Chrome Animated CSS3 3D Cube with hover state problems

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, css, webkit-transform

First off, I got the code for this awesome 3D cube from: http://www.paulrhayes.com/2009-07/animated-css3-cube-interface-using-3d-transforms/

What I am trying to do is add some divs on each face with hover states. So far it seems to be working for the most part, however, certain rotation states cause the hover states to fail in Chrome (works fine in Mozilla). Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/BUbeQ/1/

Simplest arrow key actions to reproduce the problem: Down-Right OR Down-Left-Left (Note: Make sure you click anywhere inside the result window first or else the arrow keys won't work)

Any help on how to get the hover states to always work will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "hover states"? Also noticed the `perspective` property is apparently not working in Firefox, but it is in Chrome

Comment: @MusikAnimal: They mean hovering over the small `div` on one of the faces of the cube. And yes, I noticed too that the `perspective` property is working in Chrome but not Firefox as well.

Comment: @MusikAnimal I am talking about the div with class "cell". Its background should change color when you hover over it. Also, it looks like the perspective property is not yet supported by Mozilla? Looks like the problem still exists in chrome even if you remove the perspective property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was a bug in chrome at the time of the question. I do not see any problems in the most current version of chrome (28.0.1500.95)